# can't get a background image to appear in bootstrap, maybe footer issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I think what is happening here is the footer I've made is not clearing the background image and is covering it up.

I've messed around with this in so many ways and I'm frustrated at this point because I can't seem to get the background image to appear! It's just a header and a footer with a little space in between it (I think it's a margin for the header).

Problem is, even when I try to force some space between the header and footer, the background still does not appear.

I'm sure I'm just doing something retarded here, please let me know if you can what I'm doing wrong.

To cover what I'm doing here, I want to have a big background image that covers the whole page, and a transparent floating box over the image with some information on it, a header and a footer.

If this is doable in a better fashion by just putting the image in the html and putting another DIV over it, lemme know. Like I said I'm sure I'm overlooking some retarded step here, thanks for taking a look.

I'll just post all the code here so there's no confusion as to what any of the code is.

Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Harley Fisher</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class = "container">
            <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">Harley Fisher, CRS</a>

            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class ="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class ="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class ="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Buy</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Rent</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Agents</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">About Us</a></li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class = "gradfoot">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
                <h2 class="">Contact Me</h2>

                <hr class="">
         <h4 class="">
    Harley Fisher
  </h4>


        <p><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>1723 S Leyden St 
Denver</p>
        <p><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>  HarleyLFisher@gmail.com</p>
        <p><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span>  (303) 759 8811</p>
        <p><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>  (303) 759 8844</p>
        <hr class="">
        <ul class="list-inline center-block">
            <li><a href="#" class=""><img src="images/fb.png" class=""></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class=""><img src="images/twit.png" class=""></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class=""><img src="images/goog.png" class=""></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class=""><img src="images/pint.png" class=""></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>       
</body>
```

annnnd the css:

```
body{
background-color: black;
background-image:url("images/bigbg.jpg");
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

#myCarousel{
margin-top: -20px;
z-index:1;
}

#shadowh{
text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
font-size: 50px;
}

#shadowp{
text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
font-size:20px;
}


/* navbar */
.navbar-default {
background-color: #432281;
border-color: #432281;

}
/* title */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
color: #cccccc;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
color: #f2f2f2;
}
/* link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: #c7c7c7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
color: #f2f2f2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
color: #f2f2f2;
background-color: #7e46e7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
color: #555;
background-color: #D5D5D5;
}

   .searchbar{
max-width: 800px;
} 

label{
margin-top: 35px;
padding:10px;
color:#f2f2f2;
font-size:40px;
}

.butpad{
padding:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.rowpad{
padding:20px;
}

.stackpad{
padding:10px;
}

.carousel-inner img{
margin:auto;
}

.grad{
background:#432281;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#432281, #41335b); /* For Safari 5.1 to      6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#432281, #41335b); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#432281, #41335b); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#432281, #41335b); /* Standard syntax */

}

.gradfoot{
background:#000000;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#41335b, #000000); /* For Safari 5.1 to    6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#41335b, #000000); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#41335b, #000000); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#41335b, #000000); /* Standard syntax */
color:#9e9e9e;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #shadowh {
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  #shadowp{
      font-size: 14px;
  }

  .footh2{
      font-size:20px;
  }

  .footh4{
      font-size:16px;
  }

  .footp{
      font-size:13px;
  }

  label{
      font-size: 25px;
  }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and this is what I get (just changing the value of background-style):

[image]

My guess is that you are using a wrong path in the `background-image` style

Comment: I hope that's what it is! Thank you, I think it's because I copied this folder from a template project I made, and the "images" folder is still routing to the old template folder. Told you it was retarded! :D

Comment: ^_^ don't worry, that happens! glad to help you

Comment: actually, that wasn't it... :/ I changed the path and still, just get black.

I thought it was but after putting the image in an "images" folder it still did not show up. I even tried just putting the image in the same folder as the html document and got nothing.

I'm guessing this is the right format for a background-image url?:

    background-image:url("path.jpg");

Comment: Yep, dang I think you already moved on but it's not working still :/ weird that you were able to just modify the path and make it work, yet I still have no background showing up.. I'm just using google chrome and notepad ++,, 

I recently took the entire footer out to see if it was just covering it, but the whole background was just black so I know it has something to do with the way I'm calling it up with the css background-image

Comment: mmmh... try using the full url of the image, not a relative path. In my test used a random background I found on Google, with the full url. Also, Bootstrap JS and CSS from the cdn.